# Tool to Duplicate Content from One Platform to Another?

Tags: windows, web-apps, cms, web, duplicate-files

Is there a recommended tool that's platform agnostic that can "clone" or "duplicate" content to another [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)¹ that's to be decided?

We are trying to figure out how to move our site without complications, and/or issues.

Something that's not command-line would be preferable as I won't be able to handle that.

Any suggestions?

¹ <sub>A content management system (CMS) manages the creation and modification of [digital content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_content).</sub>

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's your source and target CMS?

Comment: @onurcano22 The question states that the target CMS is "to be decided". The source CMS ought to be already known to the asker, though.

Comment: Have a look at your current CMS's Export capabilities, including plugins. Then you can decide based on which CMS has Import capabilities to match. Personally, I think that this is the wrong question and that you ought to be telling us what features are important to you (obviously, your current CMS does not provide some of them), and asking us to recommend a new CMS - or looking at [the CMS matrix](http://www.cmsmatrix.org/)